Using the number $3$ exactly twice and allowed mathematical operators, how can you create the number $20$ without using any other number?
Using the number $3$ exactly twice and allowed mathematical operators, how can you create the number $20$ without using any other number?
The allowed mathematical operators include the four basic operations (addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division), radicals, factorials, trigonometric functions, floor and ceiling functions, and hyperbolic functions.
My attempt:
$ \frac{3!}{0.3} = 20 $
However, this solution includes the number $0$, which is not allowed. How can I achieve $20$ using only the number $3$ exactly twice?

Consider the mathematical operator which is identically equal to $20$. To make the question interesting you have to specify which operations are allowed.

Invent an operation called anything you want (say $K$) and define it so that $3K3=20$.  For example $aKb:= a^b -7$ .... I'm being half tongue in cheek but I think the question is flawed in concept as that "any mathematical operators" is ill-defined.

$0.3$ uses $0$ but $.3$ does not.  But is $.something$ a legitimate operation? why or why not.  It implies a division by $10^k$ but the $10$ and $k$ are never specified.  I'd think $\frac {3!}{.3}$ is about as legitimate (and very clever IMO) as any other answer we are ever likely to get.

you are right. I will clarify it soon

$\binom{3!}3=20$

@nejimban, your solution is very smart

Thanks. Another one: $\lfloor\sqrt{(3!)!}-3!\rfloor=20$.

@ apa -- I clicked a like for your problem.

@Olive https://math.stackexchange.com/help/search?q=When+shouldn%27t+I+comment%3F

$\lfloor{\cosh3}\rfloor+\lfloor{\cosh3}\rfloor=20$

... or you could use $\sinh 3$ instead of $\cosh 3$.

$\frac{{\lfloor\sqrt{\sqrt{(3!)!}}\rfloor}!}{3!}$

Let $ \ A \ = \ \lfloor \sqrt{\sqrt{(3!)! \ } \ } \rfloor \ = \ 5 $
Let $ \ B \ = \ \bigg\lceil \sqrt{\sqrt{\lfloor{\sqrt{\sqrt{(3!)!\rfloor! \ }}}}} \ \bigg\rceil \ =  \ 4 $
$B! - B = 20$
$A*B \ = \ 20$
$ \lfloor{ \sqrt{ B*A!  \ \ } \rfloor}  \ = \ 20$
$ \lceil{\sqrt{\sqrt{A! \ }} * 3! \ \rceil } \ = \ 20$
$\bigg\lfloor{ \tfrac{B!}{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{B \ } \ } \ }} \bigg\rfloor} \ = \ 20$
$\bigg\lceil{ \tfrac{B!}{\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{A \ } \ } \ } }
\bigg\rceil} \ = \ 20$
$\bigg\lfloor{ \sqrt{ \dfrac{(3!)!}{\sqrt{3} \ } \ } \bigg\rfloor} \ = \ 20$

I'm flabbergasted not to see the most obvious solution:
$$\frac{\arctan(\sqrt 3)}{3}$$
(in degrees, not in radians)

20 degrees, which your solution is equivalent to, does not equal 20.    Your parenthetical comment does not excuse your answer being mismatched to an expression that equals 20.

@OliveStemforn: you're a real party pooper. :-)
